# Get GCM RegisterID through JavaScript at Appery.io

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I've been getting some problems with push notifications at [Appery](http://appery.io), read all the documentation and still can't find out the solution. I needed to get the devices' registrationID at GCM so I could use it in a 3rd-party-server to post information directly to GCM, and not getting through appery. Does anyone know how can I access this information? I have read from an employee there that it's possible, but didn't say how.
It seems that I also can't install Push Plugin there.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how to obtain the deviceID: http://devcenter.appery.io/documentation/backendservices/push/#Obtaining_deviceID_and_token

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately this deviceID isn't the ID paired with GCM, I think it's an 'internal' ID pro appery that talks only to thehir servers and then the request is directed to GCM. I wanted to do it alone, without passing through appery.

Comment: The token value is coming from Google.